# How to act like a input or output audio device?

Tags: audio, operating-system, emulation

I'm just i a planning phase of an app i might possibly make, and I came across a challenge. In order to accomplish my goal it seams to me that my program will need to act as a microphone and a speaker to the OS. I'm considering to make my program for both Windows and OS X, so my question is as follows:

What libraries do i need in the two operating systems to make them think my program is an audio device? I need to be able to both emulate audio input and output. On Windows i have a feeling that it might be DirectX or something, whereas on OS X i have no clue.

Also if such a library exists, and you have one to suggest, please also suggest a source of documentation. =)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make your program an actual device and write a device driver for it.

For device driver development on Windows start at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx

For device driver development on Os X start at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/index.html#section=Topics&topic=Drivers%2C%20Kernel%2C%20%26amp%3B%20Hardware